# Inequality with functions

Tags: functions, inequality

Let $ f,g : [-1, 1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ which fulfil concomitant the following two conditions:

$$ f(x) \leq 4^{x} - \frac{3}{2} \leq g(x) ,\; \forall \; x \in [-1, 1] $$

$$ f(x) \leq \frac{3}{2}x - x^{2} \leq g(x) ,\; \forall \; x \in [-1, 1] $$

Prove that there is $ m, n \in \mathbb{R} $ so that $ f(x) \leq mx + n \leq g(x) $, $ \forall \; x \in [-1, 1] $.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hints:

(1) Let $h_1(x) = 4^x-\frac32$ and $h_2(x) = \frac32x - x^2$.  It is enough to show that for $x\in [-1, 1]$
$$\min(h_1, h_2) \le \frac32x-\frac14 \le \max(h_1, h_2)$$

(2) To do the above, show for $x \in (-\frac12, \frac12)$, we have $h_1 < \frac32x-\frac14 < h_2$ and that the reverse is true otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Just to give some insight:

Take a look at the plot of both functions: http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+4%5Ex-3%2F2+and+%283%2F2%29x+-x%5E2+between+-1+and+1&x=0&y=0

If you use the line that pass through the two point where both functions cross each other then you'll get the desired line.